# Tomcat: Programmatically remove websocket endpoint

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm able to programmatically add a websocket server endpoint:

```
ServerEndpointConfig endpointConfig = ServerEndpointConfig.Builder.create(WebSocketDispatcher.class, uri).build();
getServerContainer().addEndpoint(endpointConfig);
```

However, now I would like to remove this endpoint but I'm unable to find any method that can do that. Does anybody know of a way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. According to [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerContainer.html):

> Once the application deployment phase is complete, and the websocket application has begun accepting incoming connections, the registration methods may no longer be called.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the WS connection to the endpoint through configExactMatchMap after obtaining the container

```
WsServerContainer wsServerContainer = (WsServerContainer) request.getSession().getServletContext().getAttribute(ServerContainer.class.getName());
                Class<?> obj = Class.forName("org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer");
                Field field = obj.getDeclaredField("configExactMatchMap");
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Map<String, Object> configExactMatchMap = (Map<String, Object>) field.get(wsServerContainer);
                ExactMatch.remove(servletName);
```